# Hackerrank Problem:15 days of learning SQL (Stuck at count section in subpart)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have been trying to solve the below problem
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem?isFullScreen=true
but looks like stuck at finding the count of hacker_ids who have submissions for every date in the order by given start date following. Below is the 2 versions of solution **max_submissions** which gives max count of submission per date with lowest id if multiple max dates that is coming as correct but in the final query for count I am unable to get proper counts it is giving count as 35 for all dates with submissions on every day per hacker_id. Only 2nd column which is unique hackers count in the output that I am unable to get either I get 35 as count value for all or other values which seems to be different from expected output but by logic seems correct

```
with max_submissions
as 
(
Select t.submission_date,t.hacker_id,t.cnt,h.name From
(Select * from 
(Select submission_date, hacker_id, cnt, dense_rank() over (partition by submission_date order by cnt desc,hacker_id asc) as rn
from
(Select 
submission_date, hacker_id, count(submission_id) cnt
from 
submissions
where submission_date between '2016-03-01' and '2016-03-15' 
group by submission_date, hacker_id
) 
)where rn =1
) t join 
hackers h on t.hacker_id=h.hacker_id
),
t1
as
(
select  hacker_id
from
(
Select 
 hacker_id, lead(submission_date) over ( order by hacker_id,submission_date)
 -submission_date cnt
from 
submissions
where submission_date between '2016-03-01' and '2016-03-15' 
order by hacker_id asc, submission_date asc)
group by hacker_id having sum(case when cnt=1 then 1 else 0 end) =14)
select s.submission_date,count( t1.hacker_id)
from submissions s
join 
t1 on
s.hacker_id=t1.hacker_id
group by s.submission_date;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format your code neatly and to explain your code. Why are you using `LEAD`, what is the `HAVING` clause for?

Comment: sure, will edit the format in a while. I was using lead to subtract the immediate next date in order of how dates are following therefore if i get 1 each time that means continuously via sum in having for count as 1 I am pointing to those ids who follow the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in the Recursive Query was able to solve this problem. Below is the code for it

```
with dat as 
(
select a.*,h.name
from
(
select submission_date,min(hacker_id) mn from 
(
select submission_date,hacker_id,cnt, rank() over ( partition by submission_date order by submission_date asc, cnt desc)  rn from 
  (
  select submission_date,hacker_id,count(distinct submission_id) cnt
from 
submissions
    group by submission_date,hacker_id
) 
) where rn=1 
 group by submission_date
 order by submission_date
 ) a join 
 hackers h 
 on a.mn=h.hacker_id
)
,
dat1( submission_date, hacker_id,lev) as
(
select submission_date, hacker_id, 0 as lev
from submissions  
WHERE submission_date='2016-03-01'
Union all 
select s.submission_date, s.hacker_id, lev+1
from submissions  s
    join Dat1  d on
s.hacker_id =d.hacker_id
and s.submission_date=d.submission_date+1
 )
,
dat2 as
(
select submission_date,count(distinct hacker_id) cnt from dat1
group by submission_date order by submission_date)
Select d.submission_date,d1.cnt,d.mn,d.name
from 
(Select * from dat) d join 
(Select * From dat2) d1 
on d.submission_date=d1.submission_date
;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the correct result:

```sql
WITH calendar (day) AS (
  -- Generate a calendar so we don't need to assume that there will always be a submission
  -- every day.
  SELECT DATE '2016-03-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS day
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15
),
daily_hacker_submissions (submission_date, hacker_id, num_submissions) AS (
  -- Find the number of submissions for hackers on each day.
  SELECT c.day,
         hacker_id,
         COUNT(*) AS num_submissions
  FROM   calendar c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN submissions s
         ON (
                -- Don't assume dates are always midnight.
                c.day <= s.submission_date
            AND s.submission_date < c.day + 1
            )
  GROUP BY
         c.day,
         s.hacker_id
),
daily_submissions (submission_date, num_hackers, hacker_id ) AS (
  -- Find the number of hackers on each day and the hacker with the greatest number of
  -- submissions and the least hacker id.
  SELECT submission_date,
         COUNT(DISTINCT hacker_id),
         MIN(hacker_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY num_submissions)
  FROM   daily_hacker_submissions
  GROUP BY
         submission_date
)
-- Include the hacker's name
SELECT d.submission_date,
       d.num_hackers,
       d.hacker_id,
       h.name
FROM   daily_submissions d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN hackers h
       ON (d.hacker_id = h.hacker_id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE submissions (submission_date, submission_id, hacker_id, score) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-03-01',  1, 1,  80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-01',  2, 1,  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-01',  3, 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-01',  4, 2,  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-01',  5, 2, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-02',  6, 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-02',  7, 2,  90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-02',  8, 2, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-02',  9, 3,  80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-03-02', 10, 3, 100 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE hackers (hacker_id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SUBMISSION_DATE | NUM_HACKERS | HACKER_ID | NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2016-03-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 | Alice |
> | 2016-03-02 00:00:00 | 3 | 2 | Betty |
> | 2016-03-03 00:00:00 | 0 | *null* | *null* |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1f2482c546273b5d16ae3a2f1752af8)*